# Twitter HomeTimeline as one element per page + swiping or float button

Tags: android

I need titter timeline as user can see only one element per page and moves up/down by swiping or tapping buttons.

I gess it's like a vertical ViewPager + float button.

Is it possible to do this or some other way?

I've found only as at link below or same slide tabwidget to top with viewpager
https://github.com/JSafaiyeh/Fabric-Example-App-Android

Answer (score 0):

You may use any vertical View Pager.
I found this one
https://github.com/yrulee/VerticalViewPagerSample

and this docs show how get tweet by id (long)
https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html

it's exactly what I need

```
    final List<Long> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(510908133917487104L);
    TweetUtils.loadTweet(tweetId, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            mTweetLayout.removeAllViews();
            mTweetLayout.addView(new TweetView(getActivity(), result.data));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sign in failure", exception);
        }
    });
```